# Tkinter how to trace variable defined in another file

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to python, building a tool with more than one python file, I want to trace a variable declared in another file, when importing the class I can see its variables and methods, but can't access them
as I mentioned I have three files, I appreciate your help
files I created are
Browser
ToolColumns
Mapping

in Mapping I'm trying to trace variables defined in Browser and ToolColumns , below is my code

ToolColumns

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk


#
# ---------Create Tool Required Columns---------#
class ToolCols:

    def tool_cols(self):
        global vart
        self.vart = StringVar()
        self.vart.set("Tool Columns ")  # default value
        # self.vart.trace("w", Mapping.mapping)
        w = OptionMenu(Tk(useTk=0).master, self.vart, "Controller", "Compound",
                       "Strategy", "Block", "FBM", "Contained Name", "Parent Name")
        w.config(width=18)
        w.grid(column=0, row=5, sticky='W')
        return self.vart
```

Browser

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd
import os


#
# ---------Excel File Browsing---------#
class Browse:

    #
    # -------Get excel columns-------#
    def exl_cols(self, x):
        self.x = tk.StringVar()
        y = tuple(x)
        global varx
        self.varx = tk.StringVar()
        self.varx.set('Excel Columns')
        # self.varx.trace("w", Mapping.mapping)
        self.cols_menu = OptionMenu(Tk(useTk=0).master, self.varx, *y)
        self.cols_menu.grid(column=1, row=5, sticky='NEW')
        return self.varx
```

Mapping

```
from Browser import *
from ToolColumns import *
import tkinter as tk


#
# -------Create mapping-------#

class Mapping:

    def get_map(self):
        Browse.varx.trace("w", self.mapping)
        ToolCols.vart.trace("w", self.mapping)
        print(Browse.varx.get())
        print(ToolCols.vart.get())
        self.mapping(self)

    def mapping(self):
        print('hi')
        global Controller
        global Compound
        tool_sel = self.b.vart.get()
        exl_sel = ToolCols.varx.get()
        if tool_sel == "Controller":
            self.Controller = exl_sel
            return self.Controller
        elif tool_sel == "Compound":
            self.Compound = exl_sel
            return self.Compound

    def mapdisplay(self, *args):
        self.label4 = tk.Label(text=ToolCols.vart.get() + "<>" + Browse.varx.get(),
                               bg="White", width=83, height=5)
        self.label4.grid(column=0, row=11, sticky='W', columnspan=2)
```

Comment: Seems like you're trying to trace variables that _aren't_. You need to create an instance of a class if you want to access class attributes.

Comment: You have yet to create an instance of the classes you are trying to call to look at their variables. `someVariableName = browse()` and then you can call stuff from it. `someVariableName.whatever()`

Comment: I tried to  create instances of the classesI would like to access its variables, but again I got the error that says objects not an attribute of this particular class  AttributeError: 'Browse' object has no attribute 'varx'

Comment: You're skipping `__init__` method for your objects. As they are, they are just containers for methods.

Comment: you can't get `varx` because you create it in `exl_cols()` - so you have to execute `your_instance.exl_cols()` before you can get `your_instance.varx`. you have `return self.varx` in  `exl_cols()` so you can also do `varx = your_instance.exl_cols()`

Comment: Thanks Furas , your assessment is correct.